# Text Chat(IM) using QuickBlox

Tags: javascript, sdk, chat, quickblox

I am new to QuickBlox chat..

Trying to use Javascript SDK. But this always throw

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: QB is not defined
```

No idea What I am missing.

BTW following is the head section of my webpage.

```
<head>
<script src="jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="quickblox.js"></script>
    <script src="strophe.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    QB.init(3477,'ChRnwEJ3WzxH9O4','AS546kpUQ2tfbvv');

</script>
</head>
```

Answer (score 1):

This was fixed in 1.5.0. Also currently QB JS SDK works everywhere (Browser global variable, RequireJS application and Node.js environment)

http://quickblox.com/developers/Javascript#Download_JavaScript_SDK

Answer (score 0):

Please use JS SDK version 1.3.8. It's seems like since 1.4.0 version SDK has some troubles with QB window scope variable.